# phaser 3 with es6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework, es6-class

So I'm trying to do phaser 3 with es6 classes. my code:

```
class Pcu extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({key: 'Create',active: true});
        this.bla = 0
    }

    preload() {}

    create() {
        this.bla = 1
    }
}

module.exports = Pcu
```

and:

```
const Phaser = require('phaser')
const Pcu = require('./scenes/Pcu')

class Main extends Phaser.Game {
    constructor() {
        super({
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
        })
        this.scene.add('Pcu', new Pcu(), false);
        this.aa = new Pcu()
    }

    blabla() {
        console.log(this.aa.bla)
    }
}
module.exports = Main
```

Now my question is (considering my codes) How can I get access to `this.bla` from in the `Main` after it gets modified in `create()` ? (right now `console.log(this.aa.bla + 1)` just returns 0)

BTW is there a better way to do `this.aa = new Pcu()`? I mean right now it's like I'm doing `Pcu()` two  times. right?

Comment: When is `create()` being called on the `Pcu` instance `aa`?

Comment: @tim-klein Phaser.Scene Does that

Answer (score 3):

In your line,

```
this.scene.add('Pcu', new Pcu(), false);
```

you are passing a new instance of the `Pcu` class without a reference into the `scene.add()` function. This means that you won't have access to the `Pcu` instance.

I think what you are going for is something like this (reversing your declaration and use of the `Pcu` instance):

```
this.aa = new Pcu();
this.scene.add('Pcu', this.aa, false);
```

Then when you call `console.log(this.aa.bla)`, you should see the desired result: `1`.